# Access many-to-many field in Django template

Tags: python, django

I have a model Post and a model User, any User can leave one like to a post.

```
class User(AbstractUser):
    pass

class Post(models.Model):
    liked = models.ManyToManyField('User', blank=True, related_name='liked_post')
```

How can I check in the django template if the current user liked the specific post or not?

Previously I just wrote {% if user in post.liked.all %} without thinking, and now I understand that this must be a terrible implementation, because if the post has like 5000 likes, then django will have to iterate through a huge list.

I could probably make an additional dictionary in the view (where the key is the ID of the post and value is a result of additional query), then pass this dictionary in the context, but there might be a better implementation. Can I just check in the template if user liked the post efficiently?

View:

```
def posts(request):
    posts = Post.objects.all()
    context = {'posts': posts}
    return render(request, "posts/posts.html", context)
```

Comment: Please *don't* do this in the template. Share the view.

Comment: Nothing fancy in there, but I added anyways.

Answer (score 0):

> Previously I just wrote `{% if user in post.liked.all %}` without thinking, and now I understand that this must be a terrible implementation because if the post has like 5000 likes, then django will have to iterate through a huge list.

**No**, it will make a query to check if that user belongs to the likes, so something like:

```
SELECT *
FROM app_name_post_liked
WHERE post_id = some_post_id
  AND user_id = some_user_id
```

and since the database normally has indexes, etc., it will be quite efficient.

But still it is not a good idea, since you make an extra query, and if you do that per post, the infamous *N+1* problem arises.

You should check this in the view, and this can be done all in the *same* query, and this for all `Post` objects:

```
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.db.models import Exists, OuterRef


@login_required
def posts(request):
    posts = Post.objects.annotate(
        is_liked=Exists(
            Post.liked.through.objects.filter(
                post_id=OuterRef('pk'), user=request.user
            )
        )
    )
    context = {'posts': posts}
    return render(request, 'posts/posts.html', context)
```

and in template just `{{ post.is_liked }}`.

---

> **Note**: It is normally better to make use of the [**`settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/settings/#std:setting-AUTH_USER_MODEL) to refer to the user model, than to use the [**`User`** model <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User) directly. For more information you can see the [*referencing the `User` model* section of the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/topics/auth/customizing/#referencing-the-user-model).

Comment: Wow, that's by far more complex syntax than the one I'm currently used to, but I checked this and it works. Thanks!